# How to border radius on Bootstrap ul li?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to introduce border radius on the upper-right, lower-right, and lower-left corner with 20px.

But even after applying border radius, it is not getting applied.

Here is the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/1mpx06qs/1/

```css
.frequentBookingCardsContainer {
  width: 305px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 10px 40px 10px;
}

/* chatbotListOptionsBox */
.chatbotListOptionsBox {
  border-radius: 20px !important;
}

.chatbotListOptionsBox ul {
  border-radius: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="cardContainer">

    <div class="frequentBookingCardsContainer">

        <div class="chatbotListOptionsBox">

            <!-- List Group Start -->
            <ul class="list-group rounded-right rounded-bottom">
                <li class="list-group-item rounded-0 rounded-right rounded-bottom">Cras justo odio</li>
                <li class="list-group-item rounded-0 rounded-right rounded-bottom">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                <li class="list-group-item rounded-0 rounded-right rounded-bottom">Morbi leo risus</li>
                <li class="list-group-item rounded-0 rounded-right rounded-bottom">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
                <li class="list-group-item rounded-0 rounded-right rounded-bottom">Vestibulum at eros</li>
            </ul>
            <!-- List Group End -->

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove the `rounded-0` class..

Comment: yeah, removing rounded-0 does give me a very small radius. It want radius to be of 20px; How do I do that?

Comment: let me write you an answer, just give me a sec or two since I'm @ work atm..

Comment: sure, thank you so much.

Comment: If possible, please include why does border-radius: 20px; does not directly work, in your answer.

Comment: please see my answer with the explanation and conclusion ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will produce the layout you want:

html:

```
<div id="cardContainer">
  <div class="frequentBookingCardsContainer">
    <div class="chatbotListOptionsBox">
      <!-- List Group Start -->
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item rounded-top-right-20">Cras justo odio</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item rounded-bottom-20">Vestibulum at eros</li>
      </ul>
      <!-- List Group End --> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
/* Carousel data container */
.frequentBookingCardsContainer {
  width: 305px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 10px 40px 10px;
}

.rounded-top-right-20 {
  border-top-right-radius: 20px!important;
}

.rounded-bottom-20 {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px!important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px!important;
}
```

Result:

[image]

If you want to have them applied to each list-item you can use the following snippet:

```
  <!-- List Group Start -->
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item rounded-top-right-20 rounded-bottom-20">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item rounded-top-right-20 rounded-bottom-20">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item rounded-top-right-20 rounded-bottom-20">Morbi leo risus</li>
    <li class="list-group-item rounded-top-right-20 rounded-bottom-20">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
    <li class="list-group-item rounded-top-right-20 rounded-bottom-20">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- List Group End -->
```

Result:

[image]

Explanation: Your styles weren't applied for following reasons:

- You applied the class `rounded-0` together with `rounded-right` & `rounded-bottom`.
- Your override didn't work since bootstrap.css was loaded after your component's css and therefore prioritized.

Conclusion: Use custom css-classes in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all other divs.

```
.frequentBookingCardsContainer>.list-group {
    border-radius: 2rem;   // or use your preferred border radius.    
}
```

Put the above code in your css, that's all you need.